# node.js parse a page and catch external frontend js errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, cheerio

Is it possible to parse an external page http://example.com that has some js errors (for example '$ is not defined'), catch these errors and print them via console.log()?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Basically you need to download a page and render it in a headless browser such as [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Someone has done this already: http://npmjs.com/package/phantom-check

```
$ phantom-check http://example.com
Phantom is checking http://example.com

[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://example.com/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://example.com/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://example.com/"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities

Page http://example.com has no errors
```